# Having problems changing both x and y axis limits with qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R, and even newer to ggplot2. I do intend to read the ggplot2 book and learn about the grammar of graphics, but for now, I've been using qplot to make some basic plots.

The problem I'm currently having is that when I change the x axis limits in a simple plot, it works fine. But then when I change the y axis limits, the x axis limits reverts to its old value.

```
X = c(1:10)
Y = X^2
A = qplot(X,Y)
A+ xlim(0,20)
A+ ylim(0,130)
```

Everything works fine up until the fourth line. When I execute the fifth line, the x axis limits goes back to its original value.

I've tried incorporating both the xlim and ylim commands within the third line, in one single qplot command, but with no success.

Would anyone be able to help me understand this behaviour, and how to properly go about achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not changing what A actually is. The line `A + xlim(0,20)` only changes the display on the graphics window, not the `ggplot` object itself. You need to specify that you want to replace `A` with `A + xlim(0,20)` and then replace that version of `A` with `A + ylim(0, 130)`.

Instead, try:

```
X = c(1:10)
Y = X^2
A = qplot(X,Y)
A = A + xlim(0,20)
A = A + ylim(0,130)
A
```

If you want to see the results each step at a time you can use:

```
X = c(1:10)
Y = X^2
(A <- qplot(X,Y))
(A <- A + xlim(0,20))
(A <- A + ylim(0,130))
A
```

Comment: thanks so much. I figured it was something like that, but couldn't fix it myself. Appreciate the great and concise answer!